# The import com.twilio.Twilio cannot be resolved

Tags: java, twilio

I want to use the Twilio API to allow users from my web application to make calls or send messages. So far I only wrote this basic code:

```
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Call;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;

public class Main {

      public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXX";
      public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "XX";

      public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
            Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

            Call call = Call.creator(new PhoneNumber("+40742000000"), new PhoneNumber("+40742000000),
                new URI("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")).create();

            System.out.println(call.getSid());
          }
```

This is the place where my JAR is stored now(the end of Referenced Libraries)
[image]

It just says that the imports Twilio cannot be resolved. I have Java version 8, so it should be working like this. I also download the JARs and followed the instalation from [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java) page. Still not working. Does any of you have an idea how to make it work?

Comment: You probably have to include a path to the Twilio files as part of your IDE project or build script.

Comment: Are you using Maven or Gradle or not?

Comment: Nope, I'm not using any of those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are using the [version 7 Twilio Java library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java) then you no longer need to `import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;`. In fact, that is no longer there, so this might be causing your import issues.

Also, make sure you have only one version of the JAR in your project. And make sure to keep up to date, the current version, as of writing, is [7.14.4](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/twilio/sdk/twilio/7.14.4/).

Check out the docs on [making a call with Twilio in Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls?code-sample=code-make-an-outbound-call&code-language=java&code-sdk-version=7.x). You'll find the example looks like this:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Call;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;

public class Example {
  // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/user/account
  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "your_account_sid";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "your_auth_token";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    Call call = Call.creator(new PhoneNumber("+14155551212"), new PhoneNumber("+15017250604"),
        new URI("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")).create();

    System.out.println(call.getSid());
  }
}
```

Give that a go and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I deleted that import but the behaviour its the same. Same error, it just doesnt recognise the libraries. I followed the documentation as well but I'm doing something wrong with the jar files I guess, as I tried everything that I found there so far.

Comment: What's the exact error message you are seeing? If it's long, feel free to update your question rather than post in comments.

Comment: I added a photo with the structure of the project in the question. The error is simple: The import com.twilio.Twilio cannot be resolved. That's all, I didnt even run it as the errors are there before compiling

Comment: You seem to have at least two `twilio-java-sdk-7.0.0-rc10-with-dependencies` in that folder, maybe remove one of those. Also, can I recommend you use the latest version [7.14.4](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/twilio/sdk/twilio/7.14.4/) rather than an RC.

Comment: yup, this one solved! it was about the JAr file, the version 7.14.4 is working. thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! I've added the bits from my comment to the answer, would you mind marking it as correct so that others who have the same problem can see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone trying to use twilio [ I am using with spring boot ], please always make sure you pick up the latest version `<version>7.50.1</version>` as of now.

I used earlier version and it didn't work. As soon as I upgraded that to **7.50.1**
 it worked. 
I hope it helps you.